# How to write two texts files data into third file line by line in Java?

Tags: java, file

I read two files from different paths and while reading unable to write second file contents inside while loop, it is forcing me to initialize the variable which rt in below program. Please help me how to fix it to get 
expected output. Thanks in advance..!!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadingFiles 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        String inp = "location\\first.txt";
        String two = "location\\second.txt";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inp));
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(two));

        String st,rt;
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("location"));
        while((st=br.readLine())!= null || (rt=br2.readLine())!= null )
        {
            bw.write(st);
            bw.newLine();
            /*bw.write(rt);
            bw.newLine();
            System.out.println(rt);*/
            //instance variable rt of type String is forcing me to initialize like 
            //for local variable and throwing nullpointer exception instead of fetching
            //second file contents
        }
        bw.close();
    }

}
```

Please find my program above, i am trying to write two text files contents
into third file. And the sample input and output given below

```
input
in file-1   a1a1a1   
            b2b2b2
            c3c3c3

in file-2   d1d1d1
            e2e2e2
            f3f3f3

 output 

  a1a1a1
  d1d1d1
  b2b2b2
  e2e2e2
  c3c3c3
  f3f3f3
```

Comment: Your condition allows one of the variable to be null (when the other one is not). Check if 'st' or 'rt' is not null before writing it.

Comment: So inside while loop i have to use two if condition one is for st and the other one for rt inside if loops i have to pace write content. Am i following you..?

Comment: Yes. If (st != null) bw.write(st); If (rt != null) bw.write(rt);

Comment: I cannot able to use the variable rt inside while loop unless i assign as null (rt=null)

Comment: Just assign a null value to them before the loop; String st = null; String rt = null; That's because one of your variable may be not instantiated, because of the 'or' condition.

Comment: May i know why i got downvoted please let me know i correct it to avoid the same mistake in future. Appreciated if you provide the reason. Thank you

Comment: @PavelSmirnov its working fine but it is writing full contents of file-1 and then file-2
contents, I have to write first line of both files first, and then second line of both files ....and so on, so i have to store first and then i can start write i guess..?

Comment: Replace the short-circuit 'OR' with a standard one (|| -> |), since you have to read from both files. Also I suggest you rewriting your code following the advice in the answers below. It'd make your code cleaner.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov Yes Pavel, i am rewriting the code as you said, i appreciate your time on this. Thanks much..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is several mistakes you have done in the code and also there are better ways to implement the code.
But for your understatement i will update your existing code.

1) st and rt should be initialized. because when first time st is initializing rt is not yet initialized.

2) || should be &&. because you need to loop until all the files are finished reading.

3) st & rt should be checked if it's null or not.

please check following code .

```
public class ReadingFiles
```

{

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    String inp = "first.txt";
    String two = "second.txt";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inp));
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(two));

    String st,rt="";
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("location"));
    boolean isCompleted = false;
    while( !isCompleted)
    {
        st=br.readLine() ;
        bw.write(st==null?"":st);
        bw.newLine();
        rt=br2.readLine();
        bw.write(rt==null?"":rt);
        bw.newLine();

        isCompleted = (st==null && rt == null) ? true : false ;

    }
    bw.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Really thanks for your time. so as you have used ternary operator if it becomes null it simpy try to print the empty string..? Let me try with this code too. and once again really thanks for assisting me on this with my existing code

Comment: @Ravi you're welcome.if you have any queries please let me know.

Comment: Yes it is working @Manjula this will work if both files has same line counts 

if the line count differs then it wont write those extra lines which is in another file i guess

Comment: I have doubt Manju, when you have time please have a look, Thank you..!!

Above code works good ..!! 

My doubt :  if suppose one input file has less lines compared to another.
at that time it will write the file till lesser file lines count, and wont write rest of the extra lines in another file

Comment: Hi @Ravi, please have a look at updated code. previously i have assumed you have same lines of code in both files.

Comment: Thanks Manju for an update, i may got other answers but thanks much for letting me learn new things. Let me try to implement this method as well and update you. Once again Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: Hi @Ravi. it's fine. if this answer is correct. please mark this answer as correct answer. so it will be a help to others who has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with an infinite `do` `while` loop instead of `while` and manage the loop exit condition in a seperate `if` inside my loop.

Why?  Because the second conditional statement in your `while` header may not be executed since it is an or (`||`) and the compiler ignores the rest of your conditional statement when the first statement is`true` and therefore `rt`never get initiated. Thats why the compiler is forcing you to initialize `rt`.

Comment: Yes @Zich thanks for your valuable comments to fix this issue

Comment: @Ravi You are welcome, by the way, I wasn’t the down voter.

Comment: Nope @Zich i did not tell you , i just tried to know why from the person, as we cannot able see the profile, i commented in general. No probs bro, plz never mind..!! Thank you...!!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't closing your readers, and I would prefer the `try-with-resources` over explicit closes. Then, read each line from your respective files in an infinite loop. Test for `null` from each file individually before writing to the output buffer, and again at the end to terminate your loop when you have exhausted both inputs. Something like,

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inp));
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(two));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("location"))) {
    while (true) {
        String st = br.readLine();
        if (st != null) {
            bw.write(st);
            bw.newLine();
        }
        String rt = br2.readLine();
        if (rt != null) {
            bw.write(rt);
            bw.newLine();
        }
        if (st == null && rt == null) {
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Yes i am in  a hurry a bit and aware of that i have to place inside try catch anyhow, thank you and i have one more doubt . if condition with break statement will get executed when both files become null right, i mean suppose file-1 has 5 lines and file-2 contains 3 lines, in this scenario file-2 will get null before file-1 but the if condition will get execute because st of file-1 is not null. Did i followed you in the right way..?

Comment: Give me a line. If the file has no more lines, that will return `null`. We want to keep going until **both** files run out of lines (or so I assume - your question isn't 100% clear).

Comment: ok let me explain again  
file_1 contains 6 lines
file_2 contains 3 lines

in this scenario  file_2 becomes null before file_1  right ..?

so the if condition with break statement still wont get executed because file_1 still not null for with 2 more extra lines.

Comment: Try running it Ravi. Come back if you "still have doubts". Ask properly. Don't assume.

Comment: It is working fine Elliot, i am trying to understand how the  third if loop with break statement working. it may be silly doubt i guess , sorry  and thanks much for your time Elliot.

Comment: `break` when both things that we are asking for lines have returned `null` (as in, neither had a line). As I said before, keep going until both files run out of lines. English is a terrible language for expressing these things, the code is (I feel) much more clear.

Comment: English awch..!! yep may be. Thanks @Elliott for clearing me out.